# How to turn off the unity launch bar in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

I would like to use the Unity option in Ubuntu, but without the Unity sidebar.

I've seen how I can select to use just gnome from the login screen but there are some things I like about the unity interface.  E.g. From what I've seen I like the integrated application menu with the ubuntu menu up the top that unity option comes with.

So I really just want to turn the launch bar off.

Answer (score 2):

You can effectively turn off the Unity launcher through several steps.

1. Make the launcher autohide.
2. Prevent the mouse cursor from triggering the launcher when the mouse moves left.
3. Disable the Super key from triggering the launcher.

---

### Autohide the launcher

You can try [CCSM](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ccsm)   [image: Install ccsm]
 to autohide the launcher.

To do that, install CCSM by clicking the link. After installing it, open CCSM and go to 'Ubuntu Unity Plugin' under Desktop.

[image: Ubuntu Unity Plugin]

Choose 'Autohide' option in the dropdown list next to 'Hide Launcher'. Now, the launcher will show if you move your cursor to the left side or you press the Meta key.

[image: Choose 'Autohide']

### Prevent the mouse cursor from activating the launcher

So, in order to prevent the launcher from appearing when you move your cursor to the left side, go to 'Reveal mode' in the same option page and unselect all the selected corners. If your dialog box looks like the picture below, your launcher won't appear even if you move your mouse to the left side.

[image: Reveal Mode]

### Disable the Super key from triggering the launcher

Change the shortcut for *Key to show the launcher* to "Disabled".

[image: Key to show the launcher]

These three changes will effectively turn off the launcher.

---

I have used the following resources from Ask Ubuntu to answer this question:

- [Only show Unity launcher when left cmd/win key is pressed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96410/only-show-unity-launcher-when-left-cmd-win-key-is-pressed/)
- [Can I define keyboard shortcuts using the Super key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34145/can-i-define-keyboard-shortcuts-using-the-super-key)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can make it auto-hide though, via System Settings / Appearance / Behaviour / Auto Hide The Launcher.